Hyphen at the back of the titles in the list of Tables
I am trying to remove some hyphen that appear in the \listoftables (right behind the word Balance for example in the first table). I attach a screenshot. Thank you
This is what I have in the code after I load the packages:
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
allcolors=blue,
    pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}

% abstract
\def\droparg#1{} 
\long\def\abstract#1\end{\endgroup\xabstract{#1}\droparg}
\long\gdef\@abstract{}
\long\def\xabstract#1{\long\gdef\@abstract{#1}}

\def\@shortTitle{\@title}
\def\shortTitle#1{\gdef\@shortTitle{#1}}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\draftSpacing{1.5}

% Adjust spacing between number and caption in list of tables
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{3em} % list of tables
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{3em} % list of figures

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{OA.\arabic{table}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{OA.\arabic{figure}}

\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Figures}

and this is the template I am using:
 %% AEA.cls: American Economic Association Article Document Class
    %% ========================================================================
    \def\lastrev{2011/07/24}
    %% Author: 
    %%    Dr. Melissa Rice
========================================================================                                               Class ID and Options

    
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
    \ProvidesClass{AEA}[\lastrev \space American Economic Association Article Classes]
    \RequirePackage{multicol}
    \RequirePackage{setspace}
    \RequirePackage[leqno]{amsmath}
    
    % default settings
    \@twosidefalse  
    \@twocolumnfalse
    \newif\if@restonecol
    \newif\if@PP \@PPfalse
    \newif\if@JEL \@JELfalse
    \newif\if@JEP \@JEPfalse
    \newif\if@AEJ \@AEJfalse
    \newif\if@draftmode \@draftmodefalse
    \newif\if@reviewmode \@reviewmodefalse
    \def\droparg#1{} 
    
    % Journal Options
    \def\@issueName{Job Market Paper}
    
    %\DeclareOption{AER}{
      % AER is the default if no journal is specified
     % \def\@issueName{THE AMERICAN ECONOMIC REVIEW}
      %\@twosidetrue  
     % \@twocolumnfalse
    %}
    
    % double spacing and other options
    \def\@spacingStretch{1}
    \def\spacingStretch#1{\gdef\@spacingStretch{#1}}
    \def\@draftSpacing{1}
    \def\draftSpacing#1{\gdef\@draftSpacing{#1}}
    \def\setDocumentSpacing{\let\@currsize\normalsize
      \if@draftmode\spacingStretch{\@draftSpacing}\fi
      \setstretch{\@spacingStretch}
    }
    \AtBeginDocument{\setDocumentSpacing
      \if@draftmode\overfullrule=3pt\else\overfullrule=0pt\fi
    %  As of July 2011 the authors are no longer concealed in the review copy
    %  \if@reviewmode
    %    \def\author#1{\gdef\@author{Author Undisclosed}}
    %  \fi
      \@ifundefined{harvardand}{}{\renewcommand{\harvardand}{and}}
    } 
    
    % Draft options 
    \DeclareOption{draftmode}{
      \def\mode{draft}
      \@draftmodetrue
    }
    \DeclareOption{reviewmode}{
      \def\mode{review}
      \@twocolumnfalse
      \spacingStretch{1.5}
      \@reviewmodetrue
    }
    \DeclareOption{finalmode}{
      \def\mode{final}
      \spacingStretch{1.5}
    }
    
    % Default Options
    \ExecuteOptions{AER,finalmode}
    \ProcessOptions
    
    \typeout{Journal Selected: \@issueName}
    \typeout{Mode Selected: \mode}
    
  \long\def\acknowledgement#1\end{\endgroup\xacknowledgement{#1}\droparg}
    \long\def\xacknowledgement#1{\if@reviewmode\else\if@JEP\par\noindent\rule{4pt}{4pt}\ 
      #1\par\vskip\baselineskip\else\par \textbf{Please put acknowledgements in the author footnote in this style.}\par\fi\fi}
========================================================================                                                                        ========================================================================                                                                      Layout

    
    % paper size
    \setlength\paperheight{11in}
    \setlength\paperwidth{8.5in}
    
    % AER is default
    % margins 
    \setlength\textwidth{145.5mm}
    \setlength\textheight{205mm}
    \setlength\topmargin{-8pt}
    \setlength\oddsidemargin{14mm}
    \setlength\evensidemargin{\oddsidemargin}
    \setlength\headheight{24pt}
    \setlength\headsep   {14pt}
    \setlength\topskip   {11.74pt}
    \setlength\maxdepth{.5\topskip}
    \setlength\footskip{10pt}
    % two column settings
    \setlength\columnsep{\z@}
    \setlength\columnseprule{\z@}
    % line and paragraph stuff
    \setlength\parskip{0\p@ \@plus1\p@}
    \setlength\parindent{10pt}
    \setlength\lineskip{1\p@}
    \setlength\normallineskip{1\p@}
    \renewcommand\baselinestretch{}
    % skips
    \def\abovetitleskip{-26pt}
    
    % skips
    \def\abovetitleskip{-26pt}
    
    % penalties
    \@lowpenalty   51
    \@medpenalty  151
    \@highpenalty 301
    
    \if@draftmode
       \def\@issueName{}
    \fi
    
    % head and foot
    \def\ps@titlepage{
      \leftskip=6pt\rightskip=\leftskip
      \def\@oddfoot{\hfil{\small\textit{\thepage}}\hfil}
      \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
      \let\@oddhead\@empty
      \let\@evenhead\@empty
    }
    \def\ps@headings{
      \leftskip=0pt\rightskip=0pt
      \let\@oddfoot\@empty
      \let\@evenfoot\@empty
      %\def\@oddhead{{\small\textit{\MakeUppercase{VOL. \@pubVolume\ \ NO. \@pubIssue\hfil\@shortTitle\hfil\thepage}}}}
      %\def\@evenhead{{\small\textit{\MakeUppercase{\thepage\hfil\@issueName\hfil\@pubMonth\ \@pubYear}}}}
        \def\@oddhead{{\small\textit{\MakeUppercase{\hfil\thepage}}}}
        \def\@evenhead{{\small\textit{\MakeUppercase{\hfil\thepage}}}}
    }
    
    \pagestyle{headings} 
    \thispagestyle{titlepage}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    
    % justification
    \if@twoside
      \flushbottom
    \else
      \raggedbottom
    \fi
    \if@twocolumn
      \twocolumn
      \sloppy
      \flushbottom
    \else
      \onecolumn
    \fi
    
    % margin notes ??? do we want these at all?
    \setlength\marginparsep {0\p@}
    \setlength\marginparpush{0\p@}
    \setlength\marginparwidth {0\p@}
    \if@twoside
      \@mparswitchfalse 
    \else
      \@mparswitchtrue % margin notes to the outside 
    \fi
    
========================================================================                                                  PDF Document Info Section
    
    % Note: file location is produced in review mode anyway, despite code below.
    
    \def\extendedVersion{TeX: AEA.cls \lastrev \ (\mode mode) \ \@issueName}
    
    \@ifundefined{pdfinfo}{}{\pdfinfo{ /Creator (\extendedVersion)}}
    
    % As of July 2011 the authors are no longer concealed in the review copy
    %\@ifundefined{pdfinfo}{}{
    %\if@reviewmode
    %\pdfinfo
    %{ /Title ()
    %/Location ()
    %/Creator (\extendedVersion)}
    %\else
    %\pdfinfo
    %{ /Creator (\extendedVersion)}
    %\fi}
    
========================================================================                                                                 Frontmatter

    
    % document variables
    \def\issueName#1{\gdef\@issueName{#1}}
    
    % blank
    \long\gdef\@blank{}
    
    % JEL Classifications
    \long\gdef\@JEL{}
    \long\def\JEL#1{\long\gdef\@JEL{#1}}
    
    % Keywords
    \long\gdef\@Keywords{}
    \long\def\Keywords#1{\long\gdef\@Keywords{#1}}
    
    % Publication Data
    \long\gdef\@pubYear{Year}
    \long\def\pubYear#1{\long\gdef\@pubYear{#1}}
    
    \long\gdef\@pubMonth{Month}
    \long\def\pubMonth#1{\long\gdef\@pubMonth{#1}}
    
    \long\gdef\@pubVolume{Volume}
    \long\def\pubVolume#1{\long\gdef\@pubVolume{#1}}
    
    \long\gdef\@pubIssue{Issue}
    \long\def\pubIssue#1{\long\gdef\@pubIssue{#1}}
    
    % draft date (revision date in draft mode)
    \def\draftDate{\if@draftmode\vspace{12pt}\begin{center}Draft: \@date\end{center}\par
    \else\relax\fi}
    
    % abstract
    \def\droparg#1{} 
    \long\def\abstract#1\end{\endgroup\xabstract{#1}\droparg}
    \long\gdef\@abstract{Your abstract here, please.}
    \long\def\xabstract#1{\long\gdef\@abstract{#1}}
    
    \def\@shortTitle{\@title}
    \def\shortTitle#1{\gdef\@shortTitle{#1}}
    
    % frontmatter
    
    \newcommand\maketitle{
      {\renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
        \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}%
        \long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 1em\noindent
                \hb@xt@2.0em{%
                    \hss\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark\rule{0.5em}{0pt}}}##1}%
        \if@twocolumn
          \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
            \@maketitle
          \else
            \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
          \fi
        \else
          \newpage
          \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
          \@maketitle
        \fi
        \@thanks
      }
      \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
      \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@arabic\c@footnote}%
    }
    
    % Frontmatter for AER (default) 
    \newlength\abstractIndent
    \newlength\abstractWidth
    \setlength{\abstractIndent}{14pt}
    \setlength{\abstractWidth}{\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\abstractWidth}{-2\abstractIndent}
    \newcommand\@maketitle{%
      \pagestyle{headings}
      \thispagestyle{titlepage}
      \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
        \begin{center}%
          \null\vskip\abovetitleskip
          {\titlesize\sffamily\textbf{\@title} \par}%
          \vskip 10pt%
          {\authorsize \textsc{\@author}\par}
          \draftDate
                \vskip 12pt%
                           \textbf{Abstract}
          \vskip 14pt%
        \end{center}%
      \gdef\@JELKey{
       \vskip 14pt%
        \ifx\@JEL\@blank\else \par \textbf{JEL:} \@JEL\par \fi
        \ifx\@Keywords\@blank\else \textbf{Keywords:} \@Keywords\par \fi}
    % these lines not indented to prevent unwanted space      
    \noindent{\abstractbodysize\hspace{\abstractIndent}
    \parbox{\abstractWidth}{\noindent\@abstract\@JELKey\par}}
        \vskip 14pt%
      \end{@twocolumnfalse}
      \par
    }
    
========================================================================                                                                   Sectioning

    \newcounter{part}
    \newcounter{section}
    \newcounter{subsection}[section]
    \newcounter{subsubsection}[subsection]
    \newcounter{paragraph}[subsubsection]
    \newcounter{subparagraph}[paragraph]
    
    % AER section numbering
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
    \renewcommand\thepart{\@Roman\c@part}
    \renewcommand\thesection{\@Roman\c@section}
    \renewcommand\thesubsection{\@Alph\c@subsection}
    \renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
    \renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsection}
    \renewcommand\thesubparagraph{\thesubsubsection}
    \renewcommand\p@subsection{\thesection.}
    \renewcommand\p@subsubsection{\thesubsection.}
    \renewcommand\p@paragraph{\thesubsubsection.}
    \renewcommand\p@subparagraph{\theparagraph.}
    \def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
    
    % AER section skips
    \def\abovesectionskip{11pt \@plus 2pt \@minus 2pt}
    \def\belowsectionskip{11pt \@plus 2pt \@minus 2pt}
    \def\abovesubsectionskip{\abovesectionskip}
    \def\belowsubsectionskip{\belowsectionskip}
    \def\abovesubsubsectionskip{\abovesectionskip}
    \def\belowsubsubsectionskip{\belowsectionskip}
    \def\subsubsectionindent{\z@}
    \def\headingsuffix{}
    
    
    \newcommand\part{%
       \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
       \par
       \addvspace{4ex}%
       \@afterindentfalse
       \secdef\@part\@spart}
    
    \def\@part[#1]#2{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \refstepcounter{part}%
          \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
        \else
          \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
        \fi
        {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
         \interlinepenalty \@M
         \normalfont
         \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
           \Large\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
           \par\nobreak
         \fi
         \huge \bfseries #2%
         \markboth{}{}\par}%
        \nobreak
        \vskip 3ex
        \@afterheading}
    \def\@spart#1{%
        {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
         \interlinepenalty \@M
         \normalfont
         \huge \bfseries #1\par}%
         \nobreak
         \vskip 3ex
         \@afterheading}
    
    \def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
        \let\@svsec\@empty
      \else
        \refstepcounter{#1}%
        \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
      \fi
      \@tempskipa #5\relax
      \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
        \begingroup
          #6{%
            \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
              \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
        \endgroup
        \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
          \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
            \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
          \fi
          #7}%
      \else
        \def\@svsechd{%
          #6{\hskip #3\relax
          \@svsec #8\headingsuffix}%
          \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
          \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
            \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
              \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
            \fi
            #7}}%
      \fi
      \@xsect{#5}%
    }
         
    \newcommand\section{%
    \@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
    {\abovesectionskip}%
    {\belowsectionskip}%
    {\bfseries\sectionsize\center}}
    
    \newcommand\subsection{%
    \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {\abovesubsectionskip}%
    {\belowsubsectionskip}%
    {\itshape\sectionsize\center}}
    
    \newcommand\subsubsection{%
    \def\headingsuffix{. ---\ }
    \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\subsubsectionindent}%
    {\abovesubsubsectionskip}%
    {\belowsubsubsectionskip}%
    {\scshape\sectionsize\center}}
    
    % paragraph and subparagraph are not used - they are included for compatibility with hyperref.
    %\newcommand\paragraph{%
    %\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
    %{\abovesectionskip}%
    %{\belowsectionskip}%
    %{\sectionsize\itshape\center}}
    
    %\newcommand\subparagraph{%
    %\@startsection{subparagraph}{4}{\z@}%
    %{\abovesectionskip}%
    %{\belowsectionskip}%
    %{\sectionsize\upshape\center}}
    
    \newcommand\paragraph{\subsubsection}
    \newcommand\subparagraph{\subsubsection}
    
    \def\appendixsectionstyle{\scshape\sectionsize\center}
    \def\appendixsubsectionstyle{\itshape\sectionsize\center}
    \def\captionstyle{\scshape}
    
    % ========================================================================
 Package Compatibility
    
    \newcommand\tableofcontents{} 
    % for compatibility with packages that overload this command
    
    % ========================================================================                                                                  Environments
    
    \newenvironment{verse}
      {\let\\\@centercr
       \list{}{\itemsep      \z@
               \itemindent   -1.5em%
               \listparindent\itemindent
               \rightmargin  \leftmargin
               \advance\leftmargin 1.5em}%
       \item\relax}
      {\endlist}
      
    \newenvironment{quotation}
      {\list{}{\listparindent 1.5em%
               \itemindent    \listparindent
               \rightmargin   \leftmargin
               \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
       \item\relax}
      {\endlist}
    
    \newenvironment{quote}
      {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
       \item\relax}
      {\endlist}
    
    % ========================================================================                                                                         Lists
    
    \setlength\partopsep{2\p@ \@plus1\p@ \@minus 1\p@}
    \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
                \parsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@
                \topsep 8\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
                \itemsep4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@}
    \let\@listI\@listi
    \@listi
    \def\@listii {\leftmargin\leftmarginii
                  \labelwidth\leftmarginii
                  \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
                  \topsep    4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@
                  \parsep    2\p@ \@plus\p@  \@minus\p@
                  \itemsep   \parsep}
    \def\@listiii{\leftmargin\leftmarginiii
                  \labelwidth\leftmarginiii
                  \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
                  \topsep    2\p@ \@plus\p@\@minus\p@
                  \parsep    \z@
                  \partopsep \p@ \@plus\z@ \@minus\p@
                  \itemsep   \topsep}
    \def\@listiv {\leftmargin\leftmarginiv
                  \labelwidth\leftmarginiv
                  \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
    \def\@listv  {\leftmargin\leftmarginv
                  \labelwidth\leftmarginv
                  \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
    \def\@listvi {\leftmargin\leftmarginvi
                  \labelwidth\leftmarginvi
                  \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
    
    \if@twocolumn
      \setlength\leftmargini  {2em}
    \else
      \setlength\leftmargini  {2.5em}
    \fi
    \leftmargin  \leftmargini
    \setlength\leftmarginii  {2.2em}
    \setlength\leftmarginiii {1.87em}
    \setlength\leftmarginiv  {1.7em}
    \if@twocolumn
      \setlength\leftmarginv  {.5em}
      \setlength\leftmarginvi {.5em}
    \else
      \setlength\leftmarginv  {1em}
      \setlength\leftmarginvi {1em}
    \fi
    \setlength  \labelsep  {.5em}
    \setlength  \labelwidth{\leftmargini}
    \addtolength\labelwidth{-\labelsep}
    \@beginparpenalty -\@lowpenalty
    \@endparpenalty   -\@lowpenalty
    \@itempenalty     -\@lowpenalty
    \renewcommand\theenumi{\@arabic\c@enumi}
    \renewcommand\theenumii{\@alph\c@enumii}
    \renewcommand\theenumiii{\@roman\c@enumiii}
    \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@Alph\c@enumiv}
    \newcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi)}
    \newcommand\labelenumii{\theenumii)}
    \newcommand\labelenumiii{\theenumiii)}
    \newcommand\labelenumiv{\theenumiv)}
    \renewcommand\p@enumii{\theenumi}
    \renewcommand\p@enumiii{\theenumi(\theenumii)}
    \renewcommand\p@enumiv{\p@enumiii\theenumiii}
    \newcommand\labelitemi{\textbullet}
    \newcommand\labelitemii{\normalfont\bfseries \textendash}
    \newcommand\labelitemiii{\textasteriskcentered}
    \newcommand\labelitemiv{\textperiodcentered}
    \newenvironment{description}
                   {\list{}{\labelwidth\z@ \itemindent-\leftmargin
                            \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}
                   {\endlist}
    \newcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
                                    \normalfont\bfseries #1}
    
========================================================================
 Minipage and Floats

    \setlength\floatsep{15\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 3\p@}
    \setlength\textfloatsep{15\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 3\p@}
    \setlength\intextsep{15\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 3\p@}
    \setlength\dblfloatsep{15\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 3\p@}
    \setlength\dbltextfloatsep{15\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 3\p@}
    \setlength\@fptop{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
    \setlength\@fpsep{8\p@ \@plus 2fil}
    \setlength\@fpbot{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
    \setlength\@dblfptop{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
    \setlength\@dblfpsep{8\p@ \@plus 2fil}
    \setlength\@dblfpbot{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
    \setcounter{topnumber}{2}
    \renewcommand\topfraction{.7}
    \setcounter{bottomnumber}{1}
    \renewcommand\bottomfraction{.3}
    \setcounter{totalnumber}{3}
    \renewcommand\textfraction{.2}
    \renewcommand\floatpagefraction{.5}
    \setcounter{dbltopnumber}{2}
    \renewcommand\dbltopfraction{.7}
    \renewcommand\dblfloatpagefraction{.5}
    
    \newcommand\figurename{Figure}
    \newcommand\tablename{Table}
    \setlength\arraycolsep{5\p@}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{6\p@}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{.4\p@}
    \setlength\doublerulesep{2\p@}
    \setlength\tabbingsep{\labelsep}
    \skip\@mpfootins = \skip\footins
    \setlength\fboxsep{3\p@}
    \setlength\fboxrule{.4\p@}
    \renewcommand \theequation {\@arabic\c@equation}
    \newcounter{figure}
    \renewcommand \thefigure {\@arabic\c@figure}
    \def\fps@figure{tbp}
    \def\ftype@figure{1}
    \def\ext@figure{lof}
    \def\fnum@figure{\figurename\nobreakspace\thefigure\nobreakspace}
    \newenvironment{figure}[1][h]
                   {\@float{figure}[#1]\begin{center}}
                   {\end{center}\end@float}
    \newenvironment{figure*}[1][h]
                   {\@dblfloat{figure}[#1]\begin{center}}
                   {\end{center}\end@dblfloat}
    \if@PP % mlr 2010.04.27 P&P authors making figures/tables too small so force to full column
      \renewenvironment{figure}[1][tp]
        {\@dblfloat{figure}[#1]\begin{center}}
        {\end{center}\end@dblfloat}
    \fi
    \newcounter{table}
    \renewcommand\thetable{\@arabic\c@table}
    \def\fps@table{tbp}
    \def\ftype@table{2}
    \def\ext@table{lot}
    \def\fnum@table{\tablename\nobreakspace\thetable---}
    \newenvironment{table}[1][h]
                   {\@float{table}[#1]\begin{center}}
                   {\end{center}\end@float}
    \newenvironment{table*}[1][h]
                   {\@dblfloat{table}[#1]\begin{center}}
                   {\end{center}\end@dblfloat}
    \if@PP % mlr 2010.04.27 P&P authors making figures/tables too small so force to full column
      \renewenvironment{table}[1][tp]
        {\@dblfloat{table}[#1]\begin{center}}
        {\end{center}\end@dblfloat}
    \fi
    \newlength\abovecaptionskip
    \newlength\belowcaptionskip
    \setlength\abovecaptionskip{7\p@}
    \setlength\belowcaptionskip{7\p@}
    \long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
      \vskip\abovecaptionskip
      \sbox\@tempboxa{\captionstyle\captionsize #1#2}%
      \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
        {\captionstyle\captionsize #1#2}\par
      \else
        \global \@minipagefalse
        \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
      \fi
      \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
    
    \newenvironment{widefigure}{\begin{figure*}}{\end{figure*}}
    \newenvironment{widetable}{\begin{table*}}{\end{table*}}
    
    \newenvironment{tablenotes}[1][Note]{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\notesize{\itshape#1: }}{\end{minipage}}
    \newenvironment{figurenotes}[1][Note]{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\notesize{\itshape#1: }}{\end{minipage}}


Welcome! It would be better if you provided a minimal example that shows this issue. How should we know how you got it?

I have added the code I have before starting the document. Thank you!

That is still not a complete example. And likely not minimal either.

Sorry, but your code is a fragment that doesn't compile. How or where is \draftSpacing defined? Which document class do you employ? What's the relevance of loading the natbib or harvard citation management packages? Please expand your fragment into a minimal compilable test document that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix.

When I make some random guesses to get your code to compile, it doesn't have the problem that you ask about.

You have not shown any relevant code, the image you show is based on some text in your document,

The problem is I am using a very long and complicated template from a journal. I posted the template now because I don't really know which will be the relevant part affecting this.

Please work through the link that Mico posted.  In a completely blank new project, copy and paste everything you have here.  Make sure that it compiles without error, and shows the problem you have.  Are you sure that's the class file?  It seems to be missing font size definitions, and the lines of equal signs are causing errors.  And showing us everything after you load the packages isn't helping.

Sorry, but the class file is full of garbage ===...=== that stop compilation. Besides, the class doesn't define \l@part, likely because it's not designed to support a table of contents.

Yes, sorry I tried to drop some things because it was too long. I'll try to make one from scratch

Just to make sure: are you getting this output with no errors?  If you're getting errors, you have to fix those before you can worry about the output.

Yes, everything else works fine.
